# Populating map with new pointers in a loop (C++)

Tags: c++, loops, dictionary, pointers, new-operator

So I am working on the [Copy List with Random Pointer](https://leetcode.com/problems/copy-list-with-random-pointer/) question from leetcode and ran into a bit of a problem.

```
for (; iterateOG->next != nullptr; 
     iterateOG = iterateOG->next) {
    Node* tmp = new Node;
    hashTable.insert(std::pair<Node*,Node*>(iterateOG,tmp));
}
```

So I want to create a new Node object for every existing node in the orginal list. After running the test cases I get an error message like including the HINT below

```
'hashTable' &lt;== Memory access at offset 912 overflows this variable
HINT: this may be a false positive if your program uses some custom stack unwind mechanism or swapcontext
      (longjmp and C++ exceptions *are* supported)
```

Does anyone know what is causing this problem? I know the cause might be because I created a new object and didn't do anything with it within the scope, but I don't see a solution around this problem. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

**Full code** and **error message** below

```
/*
// Definition for a Node.
class Node {
public:
    int val;
    Node* next;
    Node* random;

    Node() {}

    Node(int _val, Node* _next, Node* _random) {
        val = _val;
        next = _next;
        random = _random;
    }
};
*/
class Solution {
public:
    Node* copyRandomList(Node* head) {
        if (head == nullptr)
            return nullptr;

        Node* iterateOG = head;
        std::map<Node*, Node*> hashTable;

for (; iterateOG->next != nullptr; 
     iterateOG = iterateOG->next) {
    Node* tmp = new Node;
    hashTable.insert(std::pair<Node*,Node*>(iterateOG,tmp));
}
        std::cout << endl;

        iterateOG = head;

        for (; iterateOG->next != nullptr; 
             iterateOG = iterateOG->next) {
            hashTable.find(iterateOG)->second->val = iterateOG->val;
            hashTable.find(iterateOG)->second->next = hashTable.find(iterateOG->next)->second;
            hashTable.find(iterateOG)->second->random = hashTable.find(iterateOG->random)->second;
            std::cout << hashTable.find(iterateOG)->second->val << ',';
        }
        std::cout << endl;

        return hashTable.find(head)->second;
    }
};
```

Error Message

```
=================================================================
==29==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-buffer-overflow on address 0x7ffc4dbbbb70 at pc 0x00000041d7eb bp 0x7ffc4dbbb7b0 sp 0x7ffc4dbbb7a8
READ of size 8 at 0x7ffc4dbbbb70 thread T0
    #2 0x7fa042ca92e0 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x202e0)
Address 0x7ffc4dbbbb70 is located in stack of thread T0 at offset 912 in frame
  This frame has 14 object(s):
    [32, 33) '__c'
    [96, 97) '__c'
    [160, 168) 'iterateOG'
    [224, 232) 'tmp'
    [288, 296) '&lt;unknown&gt;'
    [352, 360) '&lt;unknown&gt;'
    [416, 424) '&lt;unknown&gt;'
    [480, 488) '&lt;unknown&gt;'
    [544, 552) '&lt;unknown&gt;'
    [608, 616) '&lt;unknown&gt;'
    [672, 680) '&lt;unknown&gt;'
    [736, 744) 'head'
    [800, 816) '&lt;unknown&gt;'
    [864, 912) 'hashTable' &lt;== Memory access at offset 912 overflows this variable
HINT: this may be a false positive if your program uses some custom stack unwind mechanism or swapcontext
      (longjmp and C++ exceptions *are* supported)
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
  0x100009b6f710: 00 f2 f2 f2 f2 f2 f2 f2 f8 f2 f2 f2 f2 f2 f2 f2
  0x100009b6f720: f8 f2 f2 f2 f2 f2 f2 f2 00 f2 f2 f2 f2 f2 f2 f2
  0x100009b6f730: 00 f2 f2 f2 f2 f2 f2 f2 00 f2 f2 f2 f2 f2 f2 f2
  0x100009b6f740: 00 f2 f2 f2 f2 f2 f2 f2 00 f2 f2 f2 f2 f2 f2 f2
  0x100009b6f750: 00 f2 f2 f2 f2 f2 f2 f2 00 f2 f2 f2 f2 f2 f2 f2
=&gt;0x100009b6f760: f8 f8 f2 f2 f2 f2 f2 f2 00 00 00 00 00 00[f2]f2
  0x100009b6f770: f3 f3 f3 f3 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x100009b6f780: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x100009b6f790: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x100009b6f7a0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x100009b6f7b0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
  Addressable:           00
  Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 
  Heap left redzone:       fa
  Freed heap region:       fd
  Stack left redzone:      f1
  Stack mid redzone:       f2
  Stack right redzone:     f3
  Stack after return:      f5
  Stack use after scope:   f8
  Global redzone:          f9
  Global init order:       f6
  Poisoned by user:        f7
  Container overflow:      fc
  Array cookie:            ac
  Intra object redzone:    bb
  ASan internal:           fe
  Left alloca redzone:     ca
  Right alloca redzone:    cb
==29==ABORTING
```

Comment: Your default `Node` constructor needs to initialise your variables

Answer (score 2):

The bug is on this line:

```
hashTable.find(iterateOG)->second->next = hashTable.find(iterateOG->next)->second;
```

For the last node `iterateOG->next` has value that isn't in `hashTable`.